# How to loop a string in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Does anyone know why? I was loop a string by using For Loop. For, instance, when I cin "abc" into infix. I use the function as below but the output was:

```
a
b
c
a
```

I was expecting:

```
a
b
c
abc
```

### Did I miss something or what?

```
for( int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
{
    cout << "infix[I]"<< infix[0]<<endl;
    cout << "infix[I]"<< infix[1]<<endl;
    cout << "infix[I]"<< infix[2]<<endl;
    cout << "infix[i]"<< infix[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: according to your code, your output should have been 12 lines, not 4.

Comment: The output shouldn't be either of those. Please supply a complete compilable example which demonstrates your output

Comment: Can you explain *why* you were expecting what you said you were expecting?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
// output every elements in string
for( int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
{
    cout << "infix[" << i << "]:"<< infix[i] << endl;
}

// output whole string
cout << "whole string:" << infix << endl;
```

result:

```
infix[0]:a
infix[1]:b
infix[2]:c
whole string:abc
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/UPUV55072)

Comment: In my opinion we can't speculate on what the OP wants until he posts an accurate sample output and/or compilable example. As I read it now for example, he wants it all achieved by looping through elements instead of outputting the whole string.

Comment: @JBentley I gave the code based on the OP's expected output, it seems looping through all the elements and then output the whole string, to me. And it's simple to modify the loop to output the whole string by looping through elements, just remove `endl` and so on to make them outputted together.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string foobar = "foobar";
    for (auto c : foobar) {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << foobar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it you get

```
$ g++ main.cpp --std=c++11
$ ./a.out
f
o
o
b
a
r
foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

as infix[i] denotes 0 for first element hope the following code helps

```
cout << "infix[I]"<< infix[0]<<endl;
cout << "infix[I]"<< infix[1]<<endl;
cout << "infix[I]"<< infix[2]<<endl;
for( int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
{
     cout << "infix[i]"<< infix[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you outputting so many lines on each loop iteration?  You should output only the current character:

```
cout << "infix = " << infix << endl;
for( int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
{
    cout << "infix[" << i << "] = " << infix[i] << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
infix = abc
infix[0] = a
infix[1] = b
infix[2] = c
```